# Model update with Eloquent causes out of memory

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to update my item models with a new description, but when the ConsoleCommand is executed it will throw an out of memory. If I create a new item model, there are no issues. My suspicion goes to that it tries to update all records instead of the item I pointed out.

```
$items = Item::query()->where('description', '=', '')->get();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item->exists()) {
        $item->description = "new description";
        $item->save();
   }
}
```

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes) in ..\vendor\illuminate\support\Str.php on line 2710

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes) in ..\vendor\illuminate\support\Str.php on line 2710

```
count($items) = 3255
count($item) = 1

$items->count() = 3255
$item->count() = 3255
```

**EDIT1:**
This question focusses on why the call of $item->save() causes an out of memory. When only one model is trying to be saved/updated.

**EDIT2:**
Why would the following code still throw an out of memory?

```
$item = Item::where('description', '=', '')->first();
$item->description = "new description";
$item->save();
```

but not when the following is used instead of ->save():

```
Item::where('item_id', '=', $item->item_id)->update($item->toArray());
```

Comment: Just in case of potential other issues you should include your `Item` model class

Answer (score 1):

You're querying for all items, that's why you get an error. It's like copying all data from the table into memory. If descriptions are different in each row, try to use `update()` method instead to update rows one after the other:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    Item::where('description', 'old description')
        ->update(['description' => 'new desccription']);
}
```

Don't forget to add `description` to a [`$fillable`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment) array.

If for some reason you really want to use `save()` instead of `update()`, you can use [`chunk()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#chunking-results) method to load data.

> Using the chunk method will conserve memory when working with large result sets

Comment: Without the save function, the console command doesn't complain about the out-of-memory. Besides, I require the item to retrieve the description from somewhere else, so I would lose that possibility to do so, if I use the query builder to update directly.

Comment: @user2803086, well, then your query fills a lot of memory, but not all. You should change the approach anyway.

Comment: I agree, but I don't want to lose too much of the ORM functionality. This seems like a strange behaviour of why save() possibly tries to save all $items instead of the certain $item I call it on.

Comment: @user2803086, if for some reason you really want to use `save()` instead of `update()`, you can do it. But you should get data row by row then. It will double number of queries, but it's so much better approach than current one. If you have too many rows, you can use `chunk()` method to load data: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#chunking-results

Comment: Thanks, but it is more about the understanding of the save() method. as you can see in EDIT2. I would assume that just this item would be updated, but there is still an out memory thrown, why, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Your can use `update()` function to update multiple rows in single query as:

```
Item::where('description', '=', '')
    ->update(['description' => 'new description']);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this helps but I had the exact same issue... it was because the Model I was called "save" on did not have a primary key.